# Enemy animation isn't working and outputs a black screen

Tags: python, pygame

My problem deals with the pygame module
My code has no errors.
I want to produce an animation 10 pixels per second until it reaches a certain point then go backwards. But it only outputs a black screen for me.

This is my code:

```
import pygame as pg 
import sys
from pygame.locals import QUIT

pg.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pg.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pg.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
fps = 10
fpsClock = pg.time.Clock()

#colors
blue = (0,0,255)
black = (0,0,0)
green = (0,128,0)
red = (255,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255, 0)
purple = (128,0,128)

#screen color
DISPLAYSURF.fill(white)

#icons
rect = pg.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,blue,(80,80,50,20))
enemy = pg.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF,red, (100,80),10)

#enemy animation
enemyx = 100
enemyy = 80
enemy_direction = 'right'

#runs the system 

#enemy_direction

while True:
 if enemy_direction == 'right':
   enemyx +=5
   if enemyx == 280:
    enemy_direction = 'backwards'
 elif enemy_direction == 'backwards':
   enemyx -=5
DISPLAYSURF.blit(enemy,(enemyx,enemyy))

   #specifically runs the system 
for event in pg.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
          pg.quit()
          sys.exit()

      pg.display.update()

      fpsClock.tick(fps)
```

I tried rearranging the code because I thought that had something to do with it, but apparently I'm wrong.

Comment: The code after your infinite while-loop will never be reached.

Comment: What I am trying to do is incorporate both the for loop and if statement into one while loop

Comment: both statements (`While conditional`  and `event handling`) should be refactored as a whole separate functions to be called or executed inside a main program loop, where you initialize screen, event-handlers and other game features, as is frequently used in a vast majority `pygame` applications.

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have said, there is an infinite loop that is not handling events, nor flushing updates to the window.

Furthermore, the `enemy` bitmap is actually a pygame `Rect`, so that had to be re-worked too.

Anyway, the code was mostly ok, it just needed a few tweaks & a bit of rearranging.  I also took the liberty of adding code to turn the "enemy" around when it moved to low-`x`.

```
import pygame as pg 
import sys
from pygame.locals import QUIT

pg.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pg.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pg.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
fps = 10
fpsClock = pg.time.Clock()

#colors
blue = (0,0,255)
black = (0,0,0)
green = (0,128,0)
red = (255,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255, 0)
purple = (128,0,128)

#icons
rect = pg.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,blue,(80,80,50,20))
#enemy = pg.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF,red, (100,80),10)
enemy = pg.Surface( ( 20, 20 ), pg.SRCALPHA )  # 20x20 bitmap
pg.draw.circle( enemy, red, (10,10), 10 )      # circle in centre

#enemy animation
enemyx = 100
enemyy = 80
enemy_direction = 'right'

#runs the system 
running = True
while running:
    # Handle all events
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    # Move the enemy
    if enemy_direction == 'right':
        enemyx +=5
        if enemyx >= 280:
            enemy_direction = 'backwards'
    elif enemy_direction == 'backwards':
        enemyx -=5
        if enemyx <= 120:
            enemy_direction = 'right'

    # Paint the screen
    DISPLAYSURF.fill( white )
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(enemy,(enemyx,enemyy))
    pg.display.update()

    # Control frame-rate
    fpsClock.tick(fps)

pg.quit()
sys.exit()
```